# Continue make command even if one operation within fails

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I'm looking for a way to continue a make command in the event of a error failure.

I need a way of wrapping a command so it doesn't respond with a exit code 1.

```
test:
    exit 1 ;\
    echo 'hi' ;\
```

I need a way to wrap something like this:

```
example:
   somecommand && othercommand ;\
   echo 'hi' ;\
```

Where `somecommand` can exit with a `1` (error) and not run `othercommand` or a `0` which would run `othercommand`.

Comment: how about `badcommand || true` ?

Comment: Just tried it, still not running `echo 'hi'`

Comment: The problem is that `exit` is a little more intrusive than just a failing command, because `exit` actually quits the shell. If your Makefile literally contains `exit`, you have to wrap it like this: `$(shell exit 1 || true)`. For any other command that simply fails, the extra wrapping is not required.

Answer (score 3):

[Prefixing a recipe with `-`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors) tells make to ignore any errors returned by that line, the only other thing you need to do is run the two recipes separately.

```
example:
   -somecommand && othercommand
   echo 'hi'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
test:
    commandThatMayFail && otherCommand || true
    echo hi
```

You can try it like this:

```
test:
    rm fileDoesNotExist && echo foo || true
    echo bar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `make -i ...` to ignore all errors.  Per [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/make.1.html):

> **-i, --ignore-errors**
>
> Ignore all errors in commands executed to remake files.

Comment: This ignores all errors and does not allow me to pick and choose in the code.